# Catching an Array from AngularJs using laravel Contoller

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

Hi I am new to Laravel and Angularjs I am trying to send an array from angularjs to laravel controller i am not getting any errors but I have problem catching data in laravel controller and using the data 
Here the Angular code

```
 $scope.sendSetField = function (selected_list) {       
        var arr = [];
        angular.forEach(selected_list, function(value, key){
            arr.push(key);
        });
        console.log(arr);
        $http.post("http://localhost/maxo_ats_v1.00/dashboard/jobsDownload", 
         arr).then(function (d̶a̶t̶a̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶,̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶ response) { 
         alert("success"); 
        },function (d̶a̶t̶a̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶,̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶ response) { 
            alert("error"); 
        });
   };
```

I can able to print the data in console successfully.But failing to print data using laravel controller

My controller

```
 public function downloadJobsList(Request $request)
 {
    $jobs = request('arr');
    dd($jobs);        
 }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('dashboard/jobsDownload','JobsController@downloadJobsList');
```

Comment: Use a `var_dump("Start")` at the start of method to check if its reaching the controller.

Comment: nothing happening

Comment: There could me multiple issues here, could be CORS or something in the middleware. Are angularjs and laravel on the same domain?

Comment: yes i same domain

Comment: $jobs = Input::all(); solved my issue and @Sajal suggestions too thanks

Answer (score 1):

The route should look like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'maxo_ats_v1.00'], function () {
   Route::post('/dashboard/jobsDownload','JobsController@downloadJobsList');
   //Other Routes
});
```

Also, make sure you have a `/` either in front of individual routes such as `/dashboard/jobsDownload` or after the route prefix.

Comment: My bad, missed a `]` after the prefix. See the updated answer.

Comment: i added   $jobs = Input::all(); and it worked and your routes too thanks.

Comment: Hi Sajal i got another issue can u help

Comment: Sure, what is the problem?

Comment: public function downloadJobsList(Request $request)
     {
       // $jobs = CnfFormField::select('id', 'name', 'email', 'created_at')->get();
      
      $jobs = Input::all();
     // return view('jobs.columnSelect',compact['data']);
      $data = Jobs::select($jobs)->get();
      
        Excel::create('Job', function($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($data);
            });
         })->download('xlsx');



     }

Comment: check this code file not getting downloaded instead getting some response to angular

Comment: Sajal r u there

Comment: Code block seems fine. What is the response to angular? You could post this as a separate question as it caters to laravel jobs.

Comment: please check     
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077081/cant-download-excel-file-when-calling-laravel-controller-from-angularjs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149109/discussion-between-sandeep-garapati-and-sajal).